# Undefined symbols for architecture i386, building for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks, undefined

I have downloaded the iProcessing framework (lets you build native javascript apps for iPhone) and when I try to compile, I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50", referenced from:
      -[TiUIiOSAdViewProxy SIZE_320x50] in TiUIiOSAdViewProxy.o
  "_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32", referenced from:
      -[TiUIiOSAdViewProxy SIZE_480x32] in TiUIiOSAdViewProxy.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TiUIiOSAdView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These three build errors are preventing the app from compiling properly. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix them?

Other info: I'm new to Obj-C, as you can see, and I'm hoping to use this framework as a springboard to get me into real iOS programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you link in the iAd framework to your project. Do this by going to your project settings in Xcode. Then select your target and in the right pane go to "Build Phases." Then in the "Link Binary with Libraries" section hit the "+" button to add more frameworks. Select iAd.framework click "Add" and then rebuild.

The screen looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Also, I appreciate how you took a screenshot, it is so much more helpful.